# CoreData: base class attributes not persistent

Tags: objective-c, core-data, derived-class, core-data-migration, object-persistence

I have created a simple base class with 3 parameters (`OBJECT1`, see below) and implemented a Core Data model where there is one entity derived from this class, with one attribute (order).

Problem is, when I save the context, only the dynamic parameters (created in the model) are stored in the sql file, those that are not included in the model (created manually) do not persist...
So the `name1`, `name2` and `name3` params have values during the first time I create the object BUT at the next App run, since I don't create them anymore... they are null...

Same story if I create a derived classes from `OBJECT1` class...

Is there a way to store the whole object permanently and use Core Data model only for those key attributes that require indexing?

BASE OBJECT1:

```
@interface OBJECT1 : NSManagedObject
{
    NSString *name1;
    NSString *name2;
    NSString *name3;
}

    @properties (nonatomic,assign) NSNumber *order;
    @properties (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name1;
    @properties (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name2;
    @properties (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name3;

@end

@implementation OBJECT1

    @dynamic order;

    @synthesize name1;
    @synthesize name2;
    @synthesize nam3;

@end
```

Comment: Any problems in using `name1`, `name2`, `name3` in the same way as `order`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed object classes are normal classes, you can add instance variables to them and use them. That doesn't mean that this data will magically get saved because it is unrelated to the Core Data store.

If you're using Core Data, add all of the information that you want to be persisted into the model so that Core Data can control / save it for you. Running 2 different schemes to save data from the same object will be confusing and error prone.